# unable to find or download sql server jdbc 2000 driver jar

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, dbvisualizer

I tried to add sqlserver 2000 jar file in DBVisualizer tool. I am facing below issue.

This driver requires a JDBC driver class named:
    com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver.

The problem is however that this driver class could not be found in the loaded file(s).
You may now load the correct driver file(s) or continue to the next wizard page using
the current driver class which is:
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

It is highly recommended that you load the correct file(s).

but i am unable to find/download the jar file with class name "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
All jar files with class name "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" only.
Anyone Could you please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use that ancient driver version? The tool seems to want and expect the newer driver anyway. And newer versions can connect to SQL Server 2000 (maybe not the latest versions, but for example version 3.0 supports SQL Server 2000).

Comment: DB visualizer free 9.2 tool expecting old jar file only We tested with multiple jar file of sqlserver 2005 and above.

Comment: Well, then I totally read your question wrong, you might want to consider revising your question to be more clear. You might also want to indicate which version of DBVisualizer you are using, where you got it (because there seem to be multiple tools with that name). In any case: is there a "generic" JDBC option? Try using that instead.